# Alter Chrome setting for all users on a single computer

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, default-settings

I have a computer on which several people log in to use a particular website. This website requires that it be opened in Chrome and that the setting "insecure content" is set to "allow".

Each time a new user logs in to the computer and starts working with said website, I get a call to change this setting to "allow".

How can I configure this setting so that Chrome uses it as a default for each new Windows user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(Note: Chrome changes fast, so answers may become invalid without warning.)

The user may append this switch to the Chrome invocation:
`--allow-running-insecure-content`.

The user may also enable the setting
`chrome://flags/#treat-unsafe-downloads-as-active-content`,
although that will relate globally to all websites, so is not really recommended.

The user might also go to `chrome://settings/content`, click your site and set
"Insecure content" to Allowed.

An old registry setting that might still work for your user is to set the REG_SZ value
`InsecureContentAllowedForUrls` to contain your website
(example `https://www.example.com`)
under
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome`
or under
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed answer, but that still requires the user to take action. I want to prepare the computer or chrome so to speak, so that a new user doesn't need to do anything.

Comment: You mean the server computer?

Comment: There is no server computer, there is only the computer on which the users work. It's a computer on which several people log in, and I want to make sure that each new user does not need to make these changes. None of the users are able to perform the tasks you listed, so they always need to contact me...

Comment: Try to see if the registry update for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` can help. Add sub-keys if they are missing.